# Use of own propriety encryption in OpenVpn

Tags: security, vpn, encryption, ssl, openvpn

The revelation that the American and British governments have cracked SSL/TLS leaves a lot of questions for the future of OpenVPN. The project cannot continue forward built on top of an insecure protocol. It will be interesting to see how this all plays out in the future. Clearly this newest revelation means there can be no confidence in the ability of OpenVPN to maintain private and secure communications for users. Any ideas out there on how to fix this?
Can we use our own propriety encryption in OpenVpn for added security? If Yes, then how?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/25585/7559

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The revelation that the American and British governments have cracked SSL/TLS

They haven't "cracked" it sufficiently to make it unusable. They've been abusing bugs which got fixed long ago – some of them were bugs in the individual TLS libraries, but *protocols can get updates too*, like how the hopelessly-broken WEP and SSLv2 were upgraded to WPA and SSLv3, then to WPA2 and TLSv1. Now we have TLSv1.2 and very soon [TLSv1.3](https://tlswg.github.io/tls13-spec/).

Also, SSL/TLS is not just an encryption protocol. It's a security layer which supports several different encryption algorithms. Only some of them, like RC4, have been broken, but OpenVPN has long supported others like AES or Camellia, which are still secure.

Right now, AES is not yet broken; RSA is not yet broken; and DH is not yet broken.

> Can we use our own propriety encryption in OpenVpn for added security? If Yes, then how?

No. Almost 100% of the time, "proprietary encryption" only *reduces* security. To quote Schneier's Law, "Anyone can create an algorithm that he himself can't break", and the only reason it *seems* secure is because it hasn't gone through the same hell as AES & the rest. Many proprietary encryption algorithms have fallen within *days* of being first published.